# Proving the supremum of this set

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose we have a subset of reals A and a real number s exists such that for all natural n, s + 1/n is an upper bound for A while s - 1/n is not an upper bound for A. Apparently s = supA but I can't seem to figure out why. I'm having trouble even proving the first condition of the supremum as an upper bound of the set. What would be the right direction?

Comment: Well as A is bounded above sup A must exist.  if x > s then the is an x > s+1/n > s so x is not in A.  So is y *is* in A, then y <= s.  So S is an upper bound of A.  If w < s then there is a w <  s- 1/n < s.  So w is not an upper bound.  So the two conditions of sup hold for s.  s = sup A.

Comment: Actually have you learned that if B ={upper bounds of A} is not empty, then sup A = inf B?  Well... that might not be any easier but it is the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

**Intuition**: The first condition tells you that there are upper bounds on $A$ that are just a little above $s$, suggesting that $s$ is an upper bound too. The second suggests that there's no upper bound on $A$ that's less than $s$.

**Sketch**: If $s$ is not an upper bound for $A$, then pick some $x$ in $A$ above $s$ and show that it violates the first condition. If $s$ is not the least upper bound, then let $t$ be a lower upper bound for $A$ and show that it violates the second condition.

Comment: can you provide few initial steps to show that it violates the first condition?

Comment: @yh05: Well if $s < x$ for some $x \in A$ then find a suitable natural $n$ that violates the first condition. It depends on what exactly your reals are defined as, but it's basically the same as the proof that the reals are archimedean.